# SwiftUI Why do these RoundedRectangles not take up all the space in my ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(.red)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(.red)
            Text("test")
        }

    }
}
```

So I have this view, and from what I know RoundedRectangles are supposed to be flexible and take up all the space so how come when I put two in a ScrollView like this they seem to take the minimum possible space?

Comment: "take up all the space" - that's correct, but ScrollView does not have own space, it takes it from content.

Comment: By content do you mean the content of the scrollview? then again the content of the scrollview is just 2 rounded rectangles which are supposed to take all the space I still don't really get why this is happening

Comment: No, content is two rectangular shapes which ask parent for the space to fill (due to their nature), but parent is ScrollView which does not have own space (due to its nature) and asks intrinsic size of content for space to provide, but content ask space to fill, ... you see - it is cycle, nobody knowns the space. To avoid crash SwiftUI rendering engine tries to detect such cycles and just gives some minimal default space. The space you see free on screen is not that what's going on in layout engine. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view sets its content size based on the size of its children. The shapes try to fill their parent. Both are trying to figure out how big to be.

Your going to need to put them in a different container that has a fixed size.

Comment: So if they're both trying to figure out how big to be how does it really get decided? If the scrollview is supposed to set its content size based on the size of its children and the children are trying to fill up the parent I still don't really get why it doesn't fill the scrollview up with two roundedrectangles that take up half the screen. And what do you mean by a different container with a fixed size can you maybe give an example?

Comment: SwiftUI makes the choice here to fallback to a small fixed size on the rectangles because of it chose to make them fill the scrollview they would be infinitely large.

Comment: Wrap them in a VStack and give that thing a frame

Comment: I would  type up an example but I’m on not phone on the way to work at the moment